# Send emails with multiple attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I am using the following code to send emails.

I want to read more than one cell for finding attachments.

```vb
For i = 2 To n
    Set msg = outlook.createitem(0)
        
    msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = sheet.Range("F" & i).Value
    msg.To = sheet.Range("G" & i).Value
    msg.cc = sheet.Range("H" & i).Value
    msg.Subject = sheet.Range("I" & i).Value
    msg.body = sheet.Range("J" & i).Value
    If sheet.Range("K", i).Value <> "" Then
    msg.attachments.Add sheet.Range("K" & i).Value
    msg.Show

Next i
```

It does work for a single attachment of any kind.t

How do I modify it for more than one file?

I tried a nested for loop for it but was unable to find any result.

Example file paths.
[image: results]

Comment: `If sheet.Range("L", i).Value <> "" Then msg.attachments.Add sheet.Range("L" & i).Value`

Answer (score 0):

If the next column contains an attachment path you can add yet another if condition to attach the file specified there.

```
For i = 2 To n
    Set msg = outlook.createitem(0)
        
    msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = sheet.Range("F" & i).Value
    msg.To = sheet.Range("G" & i).Value
    msg.cc = sheet.Range("H" & i).Value
    msg.Subject = sheet.Range("I" & i).Value
    msg.body = sheet.Range("J" & i).Value

    If sheet.Range("K", i).Value <> "" Then
      msg.attachments.Add sheet.Range("K" & i).Value
    
    If sheet.Range("L", i).Value <> "" Then
      msg.attachments.Add sheet.Range("L" & i).Value

    If sheet.Range("O", i).Value <> "" Then
      msg.attachments.Add sheet.Range("O" & i).Value

    msg.Show

Next i
```

So, you can further extrapolate this to other columns on the sheet.